# Why isn't my fade working in jquery?

Tags: jquery

I put the bottom jquery into a .js file and then I imported it into an html file.

then when i did the bottom html code - no fading happened. It just showed the text: "test" on the page.

I also imported the jquery production js file.

### $test

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#message').fadeIn(5000);
}
);
```

Comment: Seems to work? http://jsfiddle.net/4yzde/ (I suspect you didn't `display: none` the element(s) beforehand.)

Comment: is #message set to display:none initially?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you have the div which has the id message is initially hidden ? Then this code will work fine. Assuming jQuery is loaded correctly in your page.

**HTML**

```
<div id="message" style="display:none;">
    Message
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('#message').fadeIn(5000);
}
);
```

Here is the sample : http://jsfiddle.net/sPPYf/